# '80s/'90s movie with a spaceship and onboard computer

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, space

I am trying to remember a sci-fi film I saw briefly as a child. It was probably in the '80s/'90s.

I have hardly any memories, other than a man who was piloting a spaceship with an onboard computer.

I remember a scene where it crashes and the lights and everything inside turns off, including the computer, and he is screaming the computer's name to try and turn it back on. Unfortunately, I can't remember the name of the computer. I think the voice was female.

I think he needs the computer to be able to take him forward/or back in time. Unfortunately that's all I can remember, which I know isn't much, but perhaps someone can remember it?

It's not *2001: A Space Odyssey*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Hi Luke, it looks like you've made two accounts - you can follow [this guide to merge your accounts together](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: May be something of [The Starlost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Starlost)

Answer (score 5):

If the protagonist was a child then this could be a match for [Flight of the Navigator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091059/)

There is a human child who was taken away by the ship and returned in years later without ageing

It ends with the ship trying flying back in time to return him to the point that he was taken from

There is a scene where the computer turns off and and the pilot is shouting for him to wake up

Comment: Thanks but it's not Flight of the Navigator. I love that film though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you saw [*Battle Beyond the Stars*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars), a cheesy 1980 mashup of *Star Wars* and *The Magnificent Seven*.

Shad pilots an old ship with a talking computer onboard named Nell.  The computer uses a female sounding voice.

There's no crash and no time travel, but they are involved in a battle.  Nell is temporarily out of order, and Shad yells her name (several times) while trying to get the controls operating again.

Nell does eventually wake up, seemingly back in order.

The battle is not going well, so Shad tells Nell to start the self destruct sequence, which she does.  Nell starts a countdown to destruction: Twenty, seventeen, nineteen, eleven, twenty three, did I say eighteen?  (Something like that.  I laughed so hard at that scene that I can't recall the numbers.)

Differences:

1. No crash.
2. No time travel.

Matches:

1. Spaceship with a talking computer named Nell.
2. Nell has a female voice.
3. Pilot yells at Nell after the ship is damaged.

---

I saw it once on TV in the early 1980s.  I saw it again less than a year ago.

Watching if forty years after release, it looked more like a comedy spoof than anything else.

It's a cheesy, steaming pile of every cliche you can imagine from cowboy movies and science fiction movies.

If you like cheesy movies, this one's for you.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's not that ☹️.  From what I can recall, the pilot was on a lone ship by himself. It had crashed or lost power and without the computer he wouldn't be able to go anywhere